# Submit method in WCF RIA Services

Tags: c#, silverlight-4.0, wcf-ria-services

Can I cancel Update Operation in override Submit method. Then instead Update make Insert Operation for objects what should be Update? and how to do this? I am using Linq2SQL.

Comment: Your question isn't very clear. This should happen automatically if you add object to the data context and then call SubmitChanges the RIA Services code works out which should be inserted and which should be updated.

Comment: Yes I know. But I can intercept this in Submit method. This method lives in [Name of Your Service]DomainService. public override bool Submit(System.ServiceModel.DomainServices.Server.ChangeSet changeSet)
  {
   return base.Submit(changeSet);
  }

Comment: Why isn't the default behaviour working for you? Can't you put code into the `[Insert]` and `[Update]` methods?

Comment: Yes I know. but sometimes things happens :). If I find solution I will write here.